# How to disable -Xfatal-warnings in Scala project?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to disable -Xfatal-warning for the whole module from build.sbt?

I have to work on a project that pulls a lot of different plugins and common settings.
Somewhere along the way the worst Scala flag in existence is pulled in: -Xfatal-warnings.
Now I cannot continue with testing stuff out, but I have to make sure that my throwaway code is perfect.
I do not want to try to track from what place it comes, I just want to disable it globally.

Is there a way to remove this trash once it creeps up?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If commenting out `scalacOptions += "-Xfatal-warning"` isn't an option, you can always override that setting per project or sbt shell:

```
// in build.sbt
scalacOptions -= "scalacOptions"
```

in sbt shell

```
> set scalacOptions -= "scalacOptions"
```

In case it still doesn't work (I had one of these if I tried to override with `-=` something that was defined with `:=`) you can simple do something like:

```
scalacOptions := Seq(
  // list of options that you want to keep
)
```